# UIActivityIndicatorView in an UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a full screen UIScrollView to display my image. An UIActivityIndicatorView is added to the UIScrollView, it spinning well, but how could i make it always spinning in the middle of the screen while I am scrolling, zooming, rotating?

Comment: can you add the code, how you are defining the frame of activity indicator view?

Comment: Add it to the parent of the UIScrollView, not the UIScrollView itself. (This may depend on what the parent is.)

Comment: actually i wanna know if there is any method to locate the UIActivityIndicatorView in the coordinate of the screen window but not the scrollview.

Comment: Nathan S, the parent of the uiscrollview is the window.

Comment: @luyuan - Natahn is very much correct, you need to add the indicator view to super view of scroll view and then bring that to front. In that case it will always position where you want.

Comment: @rishi Yes it is. But how could I fix the problem when the scroll view has no parent view? I made it as "self.view = myScrollView".

Comment: @luyuan - you can try adding this on window itself.

Comment: I will try, maybe "self.view.window addSubview:" work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In ur .h file

        UIView *primaryImage;
    UIView *secondaryImage;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;

In ur .m file 


-(void)indicatorView
{
    primaryImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)]; 
    primaryImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    primaryImage.alpha =0.5;
    //[self.view.superview insertSubview:primaryImage aboveSubview:self.view.superview];

    //[theTableView addSubview:primaryImage];
    [self.view addSubview:primaryImage];

    secondaryImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(127.50,215,65,50)];
    secondaryImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    secondaryImage.alpha = 0.9;
    secondaryImage.layer.cornerRadius = 12;
    [primaryImage addSubview:secondaryImage];

    indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 25, 25, 25)];
    indicator.center = CGPointMake(32, 25);
    //[indicator hidesWhenStopped];
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [secondaryImage addSubview:indicator];
}



-(void)dismissCoverImageView {

    [indicator stopAnimating];
    [indicator removeFromSuperview];
    [secondaryImage removeFromSuperview];
    [primaryImage removeFromSuperview]; 
}

and after that you can call         [self indicatorView];
and [self dismissCoverImageView];
```

Comment: " secondaryImage.layer.cornerRadius = 12;" Error message: Property 'cornerRadius' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer *'

Answer (score 2):

If you add the UIActivityIndicatorView directly to the scroll view it will scroll with the scroll view. But, if you add it to the parent of the scroll view it will remain where it was placed. So, the solution is to add it to the parent of the scroll view.

Notes:

I would recommend having a UIViewController in your window, and then adding these both to the UIViewController.

See the discussion here about adding views directly to your window:

[View Controller being sent a message even though it has been deallocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585688/view-controller-being-sent-a-message-even-though-it-has-been-deallocated)

Comment: Yes it is. But how could I fix the problem when the scroll view has no parent view? I made it as "self.view = myScrollView".

Comment: I would recommend having a high-level UIViewController that both are added to.

Comment: See the discussion here about adding things directly to your window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585688/view-controller-being-sent-a-message-even-though-it-has-been-deallocated

Answer (score 0):

Define the UIScrollViewDelegate of your UIScrollView. And in the delegate method `–(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` change the frame of UIActivityIndicator object.